# Move a derivative outside an integral

Tags: derivatives, integration

Why is legit to do the following operation (in broad terms, I do not want any proof):
$$ \int_{A} \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}dA=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int_{A} xdA$$

Answer (score -3, accepted):

\begin{equation}
h(y) = \int_{f_1(y)}^{f_2(y)} g(x,y) dx
\rightarrow
h'(y) =
\frac{\partial f_1(y)}{\partial y}
g(f_1(y),y)
-
\frac{\partial f_2(y)}{\partial y}
g(f_2(y),y)
+
\int_{f_1(y)}^{f_2(y)} \frac{\partial  g(x,y)}{\partial y} dx
\end{equation}
If $f_1(y)$ and $f_2(y)$ are independent of $y$, then the first two terms are zero. Therefore, $h'(y)$ is equal to the last term, which is why you are allowed to switch integrals and derivatives. In your expression, i suppose you carry out integration over a region independent of $y$.

Comment: Thanks, yes they are indipendent. Is this a theorem?

Comment: Yes, the Leibniz Integral Rule

Comment: So I'm confused. I'm seeing what looks like a legitimate question, a legitimate answer, but both are down voted to negative numbers. What does this mean? That the answer is wrong? That someone just doesnt like the question and answer? Someone down votes then leaves no comment explaining why. No accountability. Down voting should not be anonymous.

Comment: I agree with @docscience

Comment: People who downvote should leave a comment

Comment: What I'm suggesting is you shouldn't be able to down vote unless you leave a comment

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f: X\times Y \to \mathbb R$ where $X\subset \mathbb R$ is open and $Y \subset M$ is $\mu$-measurable (for instance $M= \mathbb R^n$ and $\mu$ is the standard Lebesgue measure).

Suppose that $f(x,y)$  is $\mu$-integrable for every $x$, that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ exists $\mu$-almost everywhere  and that, for $x_0\in X$ there is a neighborhood $O\ni x_0$, $O \subset X$, and a function $g : Y \to \mathbb R$ which is $\mu$-integrable and $\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|\leq |g(y)|$ $\mu$-almost everywhere if $x\in O$.

Under these hypotheses:
$$\exists \quad \left.\frac{d}{d x}\right|_{x=x_0}\int_Y f(x,y) d\mu(y) = \int_Y \left.\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\right|_{x=x_0}  d\mu(y)\:.$$
The proof is elementary and  relies upon the dominate convergence theorem and Lagrange's theorem.

As a particular case where the given hypotheses are valid is  (a) $Y \subset \mathbb R^n$ is compact and $\mu$ is the standard Lebesgue measure, (b) $f$ $y$-continuous and $x$-differentiable, and (c) $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ jointly continuous.